# Tiles 2, mapping of JSP

Tags: apache, spring, tiles2

I use Tiles 2 with Spring 3.05. I want to map jsp files to controller, e.g.

```
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

When I do so, I get "[WARN] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound [No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/WEB-INF/***.jsp]" for all tiles.

How can I exclude the tiles (from within WEB-INF) from servlet-mapping? or maybe I can explicitly map those files to tiles servlet?

Comment: why do you want to map jsp files to controller? Please also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764636/how-can-i-map-a-spring-controller-to-a-url-with-jsp-extension

Comment: @rRitesh, thanks for the link. What I wanted to do was to map old jsp links to new site (that use spring mvc). My original problem was slightly different. I used spring filter to dispatch request (to old links) to controllers, but unfortunately the hibernate session was not passed and each time a new connection was created - which caused the connections from pool to run out. I solved it by proper configuration of cp30:  <property name="minPoolSize" value="0"/>
<property name="maxIdleTime" value="60" /> and so I don't need to map jsps anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this in `web.xml`, you should probably configure it in your `context` file.  The instructions are available in the spring [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-tiles).

Answer (score 0):

May this sippet of my spring-context.xml helps you to build your configuration.
It is based on the fact that there are two kind of tiles configuration files:

- /WEB-INF/layouts/tiles-layouts.xml contains the tiles layout definitin
- /WEB-INF/jsp/controllers/**/views.xml are several files that bind the view and jsp

  ```
  <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
          <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="requestContext" />
          <property name="viewClass"
                  value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
  </bean>

  <!-- Configure Apache Tiles for the view -->
  <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
          <property name="definitions">
                  <list>
                          <value>/WEB-INF/layouts/tiles-layouts.xml</value>
                          <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/controllers/**/views.xml</value>                           
                  </list>
          </property>
  </bean>
  ```

One of the  /WEB-INF/jsp/controllers/**/views.xml files:

```
 <tiles-definitions>

    <!-- Pages -->
    <definition name="site/list" extends="standard-layout">
            <put-attribute name="title" value="List Sites" />
            <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/controllers/site/list.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="site/show" extends="standard-breadcrumb-layout">
            <put-attribute name="title" value="Show Site" />
            <put-attribute name="breadcrumbNavigation" value="/WEB-INF/layouts/siteBreadcrumbNavigation.jsp" />
            <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/controllers/site/show.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="site/create" extends="standard-layout">
            <put-attribute name="title" value="Create Site" />
            <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/controllers/site/create.jsp" />
    </definition>
    <definition name="site/update" extends="standard-layout">
            <put-attribute name="title" value="Update Site" />
            <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/controllers/site/update.jsp" />
    </definition>

 </tiles-definitions>
```